# Android Room: Replace existing schema (migrations and all) with a new one?

Tags: android, android-room

I've been messing around with an Android project that uses a room database. Because I didn't design the database before I started (I didn't initially plan to even use one), it has a bunch of migrations that drop and recreate tables all over again.

I've never released the app since it's kind of a learning project, but if I ever show anyone I'd rather not show them the 3 migrations in a row where I drop and recreate the table. Is there a way just to tell it to use a completely new schema, as if it had never used one before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I hadn't been wording my Google searches properly. I should have searched for how to reset to version 1 since that's a lot clearer than dropping tables or schemas.

See this stackoverflow link below to see what answered my question:

[Room persistent library reset version to 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46516830/room-persistent-library-reset-version-to-1)

Comment: Not sure how to mark this as a duplicate question, if someone wants to do that for me